# Equation doesn't move automatically to second column, when first column of IEEE is completed

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
MI\bigl(E,{E^t},E_k^n,E_l^m \bigr) =\\
\sum_i \sum_j p\bigl(E_i=0 ,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0\bigr)\times \\[-1ex]
\log _2 \mathrlap{\Biggl(\frac{p\left(E_i=0, E_j^t=0, E_k^n=0, E_l^m=0\right)}{p\left(E_i=0 \right)p\left(E_j^t=0\right)p\left(E_k^n=0\right)p\left( E_l^m=0 \right)}\Biggr)} \\
{}+p\left(E_i = 0, E_j^t = 0, E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1\right)\times{} \\
\log_2\left(\frac{p\left(E_i = 0, E_j^t = 0, E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1 \right)}{p\left(E_i = 0 \right)p\left(E_j^t = 0\right) p\left(E_k^n = 0\right) p\left( E_l^m = 1 \right)}\right)
\end{equation}
```

in this equation envoirement

Comment: I mean that when one full column end of IEEE the equation the continued equation automatically shift to second column. In my case equation remaining part disappeared without shifting to second column.

Answer (score 2):

The `equation` environment is not set up to deal with multi-line equations.

For your equation, a `multline` environment -- provided by the `amsmath` package -- seems appropriate.

Do get rid of the `\mathrlap` directivem, though, and don't rely on auto-sizing the parentheses using `left` and `\right`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
MI\bigl(E,{E^t},E_k^n,E_l^m \bigr) = \\
\shoveleft{\qquad\smash[b]{\sum_i \sum_j} \, 
p\bigl(E_i=0 ,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0\bigr)} \\
\times \log_2 \biggl(
\frac{p\bigl(E_i=0, E_j^t=0, E_k^n=0, E_l^m=0\bigr)}{
  p(E_i=0)\,p(E_j^t=0)\,p(E_k^n=0)\,p(E_l^m=0)}\biggr)  \\
+p\bigl(E_i = 0, E_j^t = 0, E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1\bigr)\\
\times \log_2\biggl(
\frac{p\bigl(E_i = 0, E_j^t = 0, E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1\bigr)}{
  p(E_i=0)\,p(E_j^t=0)\,p(E_k^n=0)\,p(E_l^m=1)}\biggr)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, I can't help but suspect that an "outer" parenthesis is missing, to gather all terms of the double summation.